# Oracle jdbc creating a table, sequence and trigger

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to create a table with a sequence and with a trigger for that sequence. When I do this within Oracle Express edition I have the following SQL statements. Which DO run correctly inside Oracle Express using the same user I log in with JDBC.

```
CREATE table "TEST" (
    "ID"         NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    "NAME"       VARCHAR2(20),
    constraint  "TEST_PK" primary key ("ID")
)


CREATE sequence "TEST_SEQ" 


CREATE trigger "BI_TEST"  
  before insert on "TEST"              
  for each row 
begin  
  if :NEW."ID" is null then
    select "TEST_SEQ".nextval into :NEW."ID" from dual;
  end if;
end;
```

So now what I do is put each of these into a List of Strings and execute 1 by one like this:

```
List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>(4);
commands.add("Create table ...");
commands.add("Create sequence ...");
commands.add("Create trigger...");

st = con.createStatement();
for (String command : commands) {
    st.execute(command);
}
```

etc...

But I get an error with the trigger statement.
"Error with Oracle command: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

It seems to me that Oracle has not yet seen the new table at this point.  How can I correct this?   Should I create multiple statement objects or try committing in-between each command?

TIA

Comment: How are you enclosing the uppercase identifiers (e.g. "TEST_SEQ" ) in your java code ?

Comment: I'm using \" inside the string to encode the quote.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that an error in invoking method `execute`. Another method `Statement#executeUpdate` should be used for DDL queries. See [official javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29).

**Update:** Have you tried to use executeBatch method? I'm trying to execute batch using [spring jdbc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/jdbc.htmlJGb-Vc1kwtIeUEI8TCYQ):

```
getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(new String[] { createTable, createTrigger, insert });
```

it works fine for me.

Comment: Interesting idea but no - that makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Check for `synonym` of the table created. You can not access, if synonym is not created for the user.

Comment: How would I do that? I'm an Oracle Noob. ;)

Comment: I am not sure, but ORA-00942: table or view does not exist may occur when synonym is missing. Have you tried commit, inside the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input.

I had 2 issues. The "table or view does not exist" error was resolved by creating a new statement for each SQL I ran + using executeUpdate method instead of execute method.

Then I had an issue with the trigger being invalid - so I made sure all the trigger/table/index names used upper case.